# Considering values from one table as column header in another

Tags: sql, sql-server, lookup

I have a base table where I need to calculate the difference between two dates based on the type of the entry.

**tblA**

```
+----------+------------+---------------+--------------+
| TypeCode |  Log_Date  | Complete_Date | Pending_Date |
+----------+------------+---------------+--------------+
|        1 | 18/04/2016 | 19/04/2016    |              |
|        2 | 10/04/2016 | 18/04/2016    | 15/04/2016   |
|        3 | 12/04/2016 | 19/04/2016    |              |
|        4 | 15/04/2016 | 17/04/2016    | 16/04/2016   |
|        5 | 16/04/2016 | 21/04/2016    |              |
|        1 | 19/04/2016 | 20/04/2016    |              |
|        2 | 20/03/2016 | 31/03/2015    |              |
|        3 | 25/03/2016 | 28/03/2016    |              |
|        4 | 26/03/2016 | 27/03/2016    |              |
|        5 | 27/03/2016 | 30/03/2016    |              |
+----------+------------+---------------+--------------+
```

I have another look up table which has the column names to be considered based on the TypeCode.

**tblB**

```
+----------+----------+---------------+
| TypeCode | DateCol1 |   DateCol2    |
+----------+----------+---------------+
|        1 | Log_Date | Complete_Date |
|        2 | Log_Date | Pending_Date  |
|        3 | Log_Date | Complete_Date |
|        4 | Log_Date | Pending_Date  |
|        5 | Log_Date | Complete_Date |
+----------+----------+---------------+
```

I am doing a simple `DATEDIFF` between two dates for my calculation. However I want to lookup which columns to consider for this calculation from `tblB` and apply it on `tblA` based on the `TypeCode`.

Resulting table:

For example: When the `TypeCode` is `2` or `4` then the calculation should be `DATEDIFF(d, Log_Date, Pending_Date)`, otherwise `DATEDIFF(d, Log_Date, Complete_Date)`

```
+----------+------------+---------------+--------------+----------+
| TypeCode |  Log_Date  | Complete_Date | Pending_Date | Cal_Days |
+----------+------------+---------------+--------------+----------+
|        1 | 18/04/2016 | 19/04/2016    |              |        1 |
|        2 | 10/04/2016 | 18/04/2016    | 15/04/2016   |        5 |
|        3 | 12/04/2016 | 19/04/2016    |              |        7 |
|        4 | 15/04/2016 | 17/04/2016    | 16/04/2016   |        1 |
|        5 | 16/04/2016 | 21/04/2016    |              |        5 |
|        1 | 19/04/2016 | 20/04/2016    |              |        1 |
|        2 | 20/03/2016 | 31/03/2015    |              |          |
|        3 | 25/03/2016 | 28/03/2016    |              |        3 |
|        4 | 26/03/2016 | 27/03/2016    |              |          |
|        5 | 27/03/2016 | 30/03/2016    |              |        3 |
+----------+------------+---------------+--------------+----------+
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant tables DDL and desired results.

Comment: Use a case statement. Case typecode when 1 then complete_date when 2 then etc

Comment: @ZoharPeled: Thanks for the suggestion, I have mended my question now.

Comment: @JohnBingham: This is just a sample data, I have more than 100 TypeCodes. Using CASE would make a huge query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `JOIN` with `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT
    a.*,
    Cal_Days =  
        DATEDIFF(
            DAY,
            CASE 
                WHEN b.DateCol1 = 'Log_Date' THEN a.Log_Date
                WHEN b.DateCol1 = 'Complete_Date' THEN a.Complete_Date
                ELSE a.Pending_Date
            END,
            CASE 
                WHEN b.DateCol2 = 'Log_Date' THEN a.Log_Date
                WHEN b.DateCol2 = 'Complete_Date' THEN a.Complete_Date
                ELSE a.Pending_Date
            END
        )
FROM TblA a
INNER JOIN TblB b
    ON b.TypeCode = a.TypeCode
```

Comment: Thanks! Works beautifully! :)